# Error occurred when returning XML - ASP.net web API

Tags: c#, json, xml, asp.net-web-api, serialization

I need to get both XML and JSON response data based on the request URL.To achieve my requirement I added this code lines to my API's `Application_Start` method in `global.asax`

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.MediaTypeMappings.Add(
    new QueryStringMapping("type", "json", new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json")));

GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter.MediaTypeMappings.Add(
        new QueryStringMapping("type", "xml", new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/xml")));
```

this code works fine for get JSON. I called API this way,

For JSON output: `http://localhost:2751/api/student?type=JSON`

For XML output: `http://localhost:2751/api/student?type=xml`

But when I calling for XML this error will be occurred.

> The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for
>   content type 'application/xml; charset=utf-8'.

and this is the inner exception message.

> Type 'DeleteAPI.Models.StudentModel' with data
>   contract name
>   'StudentModel:http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/DeleteAPI.Models'
>   is not expected. Consider using a DataContractResolver if you are
>   using DataContractSerializer or add any types not known statically to
>   the list of known types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute
>   attribute or by adding them to the list of known types passed to the
>   serializer.

This is the part of my model class call Student.

```
public class StudentModel
{
    public int StudentID { get; set; }
    public int ProjectID { get; set; }
    public string WorkDate { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> WorkingHours { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Overtime { get; set; }
    public string Descriptions { get; set; }
}
```

Part of Controller class,

```
namespace DeleteAPI.Controllers
{    
    public class StudentController : ApiController
    {
        // GET: api/Student
        public ArrayList Get()
        {
            StudentPersistent tp = new StudentPersistent();
            return tp.getStudentAll();
        }
    }
}
```

and this is the part of `StudentPersistent.class`

```
public class StudentPersistent
{
    public ArrayList getStudentAll()
    {
        ArrayList stdArray = new ArrayList();
        MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader mySQLReader = null;

        try
        {
            string sqlString = "select * from tblStudent";
            MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand cmd = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand(sqlString, conn);
            mySQLReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (mySQLReader.Read())
            {
                StudentModel dm = new StudentModel();
                dm.StudentID = mySQLReader.GetInt32(0);
                dm.ProjectID = mySQLReader.GetInt32(1);
                dm.WorkDate = mySQLReader.GetString(2);
                dm.WorkingHours = mySQLReader.GetInt32(3);
                dm.Overtime = mySQLReader.GetInt32(4);
                dm.Descriptions = mySQLReader.GetString(5);
                stdArray.Add(dm);
            }
        }
        catch (MySqlException x)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(x.Number);
        }
        return stdArray;
    }
}
```

How can I solve this error and what is the reason for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. I added `KnownType` attribute to my model class.

```
[KnownType(typeof(DeleteAPI.Models.TaskModel))]
public class StudentModel
{
    public int DeveloperID { get; set; }
    public int ProjectID { get; set; }
    public string WorkDate { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> WorkingHours { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Overtime { get; set; }
    public string Descriptions { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the action method to :

```
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage Get(int isxmlorJson)
{
      StudentPersistent tp = new StudentPersistent();
      tp = //Get data from Business Layer
      var data = new ObjectContent<StudentPersistent>(tp,
                    ((isxmlorJson== 1) ? Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter :
                                Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter));
    return new HttpResponseMessage()
    {
         Content = data
    };    
}
```

This is the general way of defining the controllers and the configuration in application_start can be removed .

Comment: Can you please give me sample code. how can I write method body.

Comment: hi, thanks for the answer. but unfortunately this error occurred. 

`Error CS0173 Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'System.Net.Http.Formatting.XmlMediaTypeFormatter' and 'System.Net.Http.Formatting.JsonMediaTypeFormatter'`

Comment: And there also have a problem. according your answer I had to call API like this `http://localhost:2751/api/student/1`. according my project I can't call API this way. I need to get *JSON* and *XML* output by calling API `http://localhost:2751/api/student?type=JSON` and `http://localhost:2751/api/student?type=XML` 

or `http://localhost:2751/api/student.json` or `http://localhost:2751/api/student.xml`